# How to make TinyMCE work with multiple textareas with the same array name

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tinymce, tinymce-4

My form has multiple textareas, all with the same name `item_description[]`. The user can add unlimited items, reorder items, delete items so working with this array name seems my only possibility.

My TinyMCE code works for the first textarea, but starting from the second textarea, TinyMCE is showing but it is not editable.

**JavaScript**

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="item_description[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="item_description[]"></textarea>
```

*(number of textarea's depends on the number of items on the page)*

So how can I get TinyMCE to work on all textareas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector configuration option allows you to use a CSS selector to target all the elements where you want TinyMCE to appear:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#selector

I would just put a class on all of the textareas that should load TinyMCE:

```
<textarea class="editor" name="item_description[]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="item_description[]"></textarea>
```

...then use a selector that matches on class:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: ".editor",
});
```

Comment: I have tried adding a class but the problem remains.

Comment: Can you define what problem still exists?  Are you trying to initialize textareas over time as people do something on the web page?  Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows what you are trying?  Without seeing running code it will be hard to get more specific.

Comment: It is working correctly in the fiddle so I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong on my page. Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, it was indeed a problem with initializing textareas over time. Had to try the Fiddle before posting this question... Again thanks for your answers Michael.